# Hign CPU usage when using Angular5 + cytoscapeJS

Tags: angular, cytoscape.js

I am using **Angular5 + cytoscapeJS** to draw a graph
I noticed that the CPU usage of chrome browser will be constantly at about 10%

When using the Performance tab in DevTools I can see that I am getting "requestAnimationFrame" event from zone.js

See image:
[image]

This is how the HTML looks:

```
<div id="cy"></div>
```

This is the creation of "cytoscape" in the typescript code

```
 var _graphData: any = {
            nodes: [
              {data: {id: 'j', name: 'Jerry', faveColor: '#6FB1FC', faveShape: 'triangle'}},
              {data: {id: 'e', name: 'Elaine', faveColor: '#EDA1ED', faveShape: 'ellipse'}},
              {data: {id: 'k', name: 'Kramer', faveColor: '#86B342', faveShape: 'octagon'}},
              {data: {id: 'g', name: 'George', faveColor: '#F5A45D', faveShape: 'rectangle'}}
            ],
            edges: [
              {data: {source: 'j', target: 'e', faveColor: '#6FB1FC'}},
              {data: {source: 'j', target: 'k', faveColor: '#6FB1FC'}},
              {data: {source: 'j', target: 'g', faveColor: '#6FB1FC'}},

              {data: {source: 'e', target: 'j', faveColor: '#EDA1ED'}},
              {data: {source: 'e', target: 'k', faveColor: '#EDA1ED'}},

              {data: {source: 'k', target: 'j', faveColor: '#86B342'}},
              {data: {source: 'k', target: 'e', faveColor: '#86B342'}},
              {data: {source: 'k', target: 'g', faveColor: '#86B342'}},

              {data: {source: 'g', target: 'j', faveColor: '#F5A45D'}}
            ]
          };
        this.cy = cytoscape({
            container: document.getElementById('cy'),
            boxSelectionEnabled: false,
            autounselectify: true,
            autoungrabify:true,
            userPanningEnabled :false,                
            style: gStyle,            
            elements: {
                nodes:_graphData.nodes,
                edges: _graphData.edges                
            },

            layout: {
                name: 'breadthfirst',
                directed: true,
                padding: 10
            },
            zoom: 1,
            selectionType: 'single', 

        }); // cy init

        this.cy.zoomingEnabled( false );
```

Any ideas how to fix this CPU issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be because of Zone.js forces Angular to re-render at every animation-frame. Try to run cytoscape outside of Angular zone.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
            // Initialize cytoscape
            cytoscape({...});
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. will this change reduce the number of calls to "requestAnimationFrame" or just make the handling of it faster?

Comment: No, it does not reduce the number of calls to `requestAnimationFrame`. It may be called by cytoscape more than 60 times per second. This just tells Angular that you have nothing to do with.